# Why the thread will be blocked when it executes the code "while (Thread.activeCount() > 1) "?

Tags: java, multithreading

Following code exists in chapter 13 of "UnderStanding the JVM Advanced Features and Best Practices, second Edition".
But when the thread execute " while (Thread.activeCount() > 1)", it will be blocked and nothing will be printed.

```
public class Code_12_1 {
public static AtomicInteger race = new AtomicInteger(0);

public static void increment(){
    race.incrementAndGet();
}

private static final int THREADS_COUNT = 20;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[THREADS_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_COUNT; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                    increment();

                }
            }
        });
        threads[i].start();
    }

    while (Thread.activeCount() > 1)
        Thread.yield();

    System.out.println(race);
}
```

}

But when I change "while (Thread.activeCount() > 1)" to "while (Thread.activeCount()>2)" the thread can execute correctly and output the answer 200000.

So, why thread will be blocked when it executes "while (Thread.activeCount() > 1)"?

Comment: You don't specify a group for your threads so it is allocated by the JVM, and it seems that the group used already has a running thread on top of the threads you create.

Comment: `activeCount` method from java doc: "The value returned is only an estimate because the number of threads may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data structures, and might be affected by the presence of certain system threads. This method is intended primarily for debugging and monitoring purposes.". So, it's just estimated number, and can be affected by system thread. You should not rely on `activeCount`, and should use `join` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I ran your code and it turns out there is already another Thread running besides the Main thread initially(in the current ThreadGroup), even before you all other threads. So, the following print statement gave me a count of 2(see the initialCount):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[THREADS_COUNT];

        int initialCount = Thread.activeCount();
        System.out.println("Initial count: " + initialCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_COUNT; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                        increment();

                    }
                }
            });
            threads[i].start();
        }

        while (Thread.activeCount() > 1){
            System.out.println(race);
            System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
            Thread.yield();
        }
 }
```

So, what you have to do is:

```
while (Thread.activeCount() > initialCount){
            Thread.yield();
}
```

And, it will work as expected.

**Reasoning**: It is blocked because all your Threads finish executing after you start them and then you have this additional thread remaining that never makes you exit the while loop.

If you insert a print statement before `Thread.yield()`, you get an output like,

```
200000
200000
200000
200000
200000
200000
...
...
```

This supports the reasoning that all the Threads have finished and just 2 are left that keep the loop running.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I understand why it happens. If I use eclipse to run the code , the code "while(Thread.activeCount()>1)" has no problem. But if I use Intellij IDEA, it will have problem. Because IDEA will start a new thread called "Monitor Ctrl-Break", so the number of active threads is 2.[link](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-runtime/src/com/intellij/rt/execution/application/AppMainV2.java)